# Iterator dereferencing assertion error

Tags: c++

I'm using an iterator to loop through list's and then dereferencing them into a obj or array of the same time, I am doing this in 2 different instances but I am getting an assertion error saying I cannot dereference the iterator.

I'm confused because in one of the functions it works fine, however in the second function it's throwing the error but they have been coded the same way.

*the function the assertion error is being thrown:*

```
Coord backTrack(){ // recalls to intersection where dead-end route was found
    list<Coord>::iterator it = pathHistory.end();
    Coord deadEnd = *it;
    coordsToUnmark.push_back(deadEnd);
    pathHistory.pop_back();
    return pathHistory.front();
}
```

*in this function it works fine:*

```
int findPath (Maze& theMaze, const Coord& start, const Coord& end, Coord path[]){
    patherFinder(theMaze, start.x, start.y, end);
    list<Coord>::iterator it;
    int ii = 0;
    for (it = pathHistory.begin(); it != pathHistory.end(); it++){
        path[ii] = *it;
        ii++;
}
```

Comment: Dereferencing `end` is undefined behaviour, which may explain everything, of course. Other than that, it's almost impossible to know what's going on because you have not posted an MCVE.

Comment: if `list` is `std::list`, you can get the last element via `.back()`

Comment: Note that `end()` does not return an iterator to the last item. If container is not empty then you can use `back()` to get a reference to the last item.

Comment: @ChristianHackl this actually makes sense, I just googled it end is a past-the-end element, I feel dumb, thank-you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments I realized list.end() isn't the last element its the past-the-end element in the list container which explains why I couldn't dereference it.